# UserDefaults doesn't load

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsuserdefaults

I have a VC that passes a name to a label on a second view controller:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destination = segue.destination as? ViewController{
        destination.name = petNameTxt.text
        destination.morning = morningFeed.text
        destination.night = nightFeed.text
    }
}
```

On the second VC it I try to save the label but it just holds the placeholder text in UserDefaults:

save it in ViewDidLoad

```
let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        userDefaults.setValue(petNameLbl.text, forKey: "data")
        userDefaults.synchronize()
```

load it in a separate function that runs with ViewDidLoad

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    if let name = defaults.string(forKey: "data"){
        petNameLbl.text = name
    }
```

Comment: Four observations: (1) I assumed you've stepped through this in the debugger. (2) I assume this is a standard app bundle **and** you've assigned it a unique product identifier, something user defaults needs (3) This really isn't what `UserDefaults` is for (it's for, you know, *persistent* user defaults). This kind of task is much better handled by something like `NSThread.threadDictionary`. (4) When will people stop calling `synchronize()` in inappropriate places?

Comment: ...and (5) don't use KVC method `setValue(_:forKey:)` with `UserDefaults`. There is generic set(_:forKey:)

Comment: @vadian, good one ... missed that

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your problem is, but here's a more appropriate (INMNSHO) solution:

Code that saves the value:

```
Thread.current.threadDictionary["data"] = petNameLbl.text
```

Code that retrieves the value

```
petNameLbl.text = Thread.current.threadDictionary["data"]
```